# Standalone numbers Regex?

Tags: c#, python, regex, numbers

I currently use this regex:

```
(\d+)
```

the problem that i can get 2 strings:

> "2112343 and alot of 4.99"

**OR**

> "4.99 and alot of 2112343 "

I get this from both:

```
[2112343, 4, 99]
```

I need to get only the **2112343**...
How can i achieve this?

Comment: It does get "numbers only". Perhaps you mean to rephrase the title?

Comment: @pst To be exact, it does only get sequences of digits, hence `\d`.

Comment: if you know what you're finding - why do you need to find it?

Comment: `\d` stands for a digit and does not include the decimal point.

Comment: @JonClements This is an example, it's not the only case, obviously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using lookaround, you can restrict your capturing to only digits which are not surrounded by other digits or decimal points:

```
(?<![0-9.])(\d+)(?![0-9.])
```

Alternatively, if you want to only match stand-alone numbers (e.g. if you don't want to match the 123 in `abc123def`):

```
(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)
```

Comment: Would not be matched, intentionally.

Comment: @pst `1` and `4` are in `[0-9.]` and thus disallowed from being to the left and right of the matched group due to the lookarounds.

Comment: It matches `hello 1234 world` -> `1234` because whitespace characters are not in `[0-9.]` and thus satisfy the lookarounds. Do you know how lookarounds work? http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: RegexPal does not use C# regex; it uses JavaScript regex. The two are not the same. Specifically, JavaScript regex doesn't support negative lookbehind.

Comment: if i want the a regex that will get 123 from this: "p123" but not get 1, 23 from this: "1.23" ?

Comment: To preserve bond-007 and 100-monkeys add dashes next to those dots, and so on. I get it now, the left side says only match if any of these precede the thing of interest \d+, and the right side applies only to what comes after

Answer (score 2):

The catch is always in what "standalone" means. Here are several solutions depending on that meaning.

1. Match digit strings not enclosed with other digits: `(?<!\d)\d+(?!\d)` (note this is equal to `\d+`, but `(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)` will start making sense when you need to match only four-digit strings). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dz5wZ8/1).
2. Match digit strings only enclosed with whitespace or at the start/end of the string: `(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dz5wZ8/2).
3. Match digit strings as whole words: `\b\d+\b` (note that [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) match in a lot of contexts, and will also match parts of decimal numbers). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dz5wZ8/3).
4. Match whole integers, not parts of decimal numbers (assuming that a dot is used as a decimal separator): `(?<!\d\.)(?<!\d)\d+(?!\.?\d)`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dz5wZ8/4).
5. Matching digit only strings: `^\d+$`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dz5wZ8/5).

There can be more variations of these patterns, just make sure you match the right "standalone" meaning.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)
```

this will only match integers

Comment: This expression will match integers only in-between whitespaces and start/end of string. For other cases, when the numbers can be found in other contexts, you can refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77006941/3832970) where I listed 5 contexts.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to match those numbers with a point inside, too, but dont want to have these in the resulting collection.

I would approach this via 2 steps, first select all numbers, also those with a dot:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)
```

then filter out everything that is not purely numbers, and use your first regex and apply it to each item of the resulting collection from the first step:

```
(\d+)
```

Comment: I agree with this approach; no point trying to come up with an overly complicated regular expression...  However I would use `[\d.]+` as the initial selector.

Comment: @pst: the question is if we want to treat "123." as wanted or not. Your selector would match it, and throw it away in the second step. My selector would match "123" and finally keep it. The op should decide here what fits the problem best...

Answer (score 1):

As I posted in my comment:

```
(?:^| )(\d+)(?:$| )
```

It will match all "words" that are entirely composed of digits(a word being a string of non-space characters surrounded by space characters and or the beginning/end of the string.)

Comment: It is interesting that in some regex libraries that do not support lookarounds, even non-capturing groups are not supported. That is why `(?:^| )(\d+)(?:$| )` can be either too "wordy" (i.e. `(^| )(\d+)($| )` would still work (e.g. in RE2), the result is in Group 2), or can need fixing (same as the previous, for POSIX users).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(?<![0-9.])\d+(?![0-9.])
```

It usees the pattern

```
(?<!prefix)position(?!suffix)
```

where `(?<!prefix)position` means: Match position not following prefix.

and   `position(?!suffix)`  means: Match position not preceeding suffix.

finally `[0-9.]` means: Any digit or the decimal point.

Answer (score -2):

```
>>>r = re.match("\d+", "23423 in 3.4")
>>>r.group(0)
'23423'
```

Comment: Such a solution would only work in this specific case. I doubt OP wants a solution that only works for strings in this format.

Comment: I dont think thats what the op wanted. That was just the first number in his example...

Comment: This is not even explaining the use of `re.match` vs. `re.search` that would be crucial to many people seeing this post. Needs deletion.